# pymssql connection does not return data and only prints the colum name?

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I'm trying to fetch the data from server so I tried as follow

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(host='xxxx', user='xxx', password='xxx', database='xxx')


cursor = conn.cursor()
x2 = 'select * from result where url like\'%get content%\''
cursor.execute(x2)
data = cursor.fetchall()
field_names = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
print field_names
print data
```

When I run this program it only give the column name, `data` variable is empty. I don't know what is the reason. How can I fix it?

I'm running the same script in windows there is no problem. But when I execute the script in `Ubuntu 14.04` the `data` variable is empty.

Comment: Can you check cursor.rowcount after or before fetchall() command.

Comment: Is it giving -1 in both cases (before & after fetchall)? If yes, then there is problem query or connection..

Comment: @HarshaBiyani Yes both cases it's result `-1`. If query or connection is problem mean how the column gets print?

Comment: ohh correct.. Have you tried with simple query? like - select * from result?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani Yep. I tried. But rows are not fetching. :(

Comment: @mkHun What's your `pymssql` version?

Comment: @Omid version is `1.0.2`

Comment: @HarshaBiyani Please check the user omid answer. It works.

Comment: @mkHun ; gr8 :) finally got solution. :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug of `PyMSSQL 1.0.x` on Ubuntu. See [No data returned from MSSQL server](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pymssql/+bug/918896). Solution is to upgrade it to version `>= 2.0.1`.

> Due to an issue with PyMSSQL 1.0.x and the version of FreeTDX in the
>   repositories, PyMSSQL no longer returns any information from MSSQL
>   database queries. This means you cannot use fetchone() or fetchall()
>   or similar methods to get data back from a database query.
>
> ---
>
> Thomas Ward (teward) wrote on 2016-06-05:
>
> This is due to an incompatibility between freetdx and PyMSSQL 1.0.x.
>
> **Workaround is to remove the python-pymssql package, and run `pip
>   install pymssql` or `easy_install --upgrade pymssql` or similar, to
>   get the most up to date pymssql version, greater than or equal to
>   2.0.1.**
>
> ALso confirmed this issue on Xenial and Yakkety, as well as **Trusty**.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [pyodbc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-pyodbc) on ubuntu 14.04